# Text content overflow its element tag

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the code. It's in Angular if that has something to do with it. The actual text height is overflowing the element that contains it.

```css
#website-title {
    text-align: center;
    // font-family: "Roboto-Mono";
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p id="website-title">Poll App</p>
```

result:

[image]

I want the element to be the height of the content.

UPDATE: Narrowed the problem down to Angular Material. Everything is fine before doing `ng add @angular/material`. Then after adding material and restarting the server, I get the problem.

Comment: is already with height of the content https://jsfiddle.net/29zf56uk/

Comment: Whatexactly are you trying to say? A [minimal-reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be appreciated, on jsfiddle or here, or any where

Comment: @JRichardsz i think there must be a parent element of `<p>` tag OP is talking about.

Comment: Use this to restart your css https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @DaniyalShaikh the code above is the only code running besides all the angular framework stuff. its one p tag with text inside it. The text is going outside the bounds of the p tag as seen in the picture.

Comment: There is some other rule that is setting a `height: 20px` on the `p`... And the text overflows because of the `font-size: 50px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Be default, the `p` tag will expand to fit its content. So unless you have explicitly set the `p` tag height to be smaller than the text content, the text will not overflow.

Try checking to see if you have set a height on the `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but I don't know why it fixes the problem.

The problem had to do with Angular Material's typography (Angular material was installed). Sol'n - Go to index.html and remove the `class="mat-typography"` from the body tag.